# Replace all <a> elements *without* an attribute

Tags: html, intellij-idea, structural-search

I want to use structural search to find e.g.:

```
<a data-foo="bar" style="width: 1px;">
<a data-bar="foo">
```

But *not*:

```
<a data-foo="bar" style="width: 1px;" href="https://google.com">
<a href="#" data-bar="foo">
```

Is there a script filter I can add to the complete match to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Set the search template to:

```
<$tag$ $attributeA$=$valueA$ />
```

On `$attributeA$`, filter with `text=href, count=[0,0]`. Do not filter `$valueA`.

Answer (score -2):

Use `:not()` e.g.:

```js
document.querySelector('a:not([href])')
```